# javascript time EST/CST

Tags: javascript, getdate

I know this is probably a noob question, My website is hosted out of a computer in the CST, I need something to display Monday at 12:00:00 AM EST.

```
 var d = new Date();
 if (d.getDate() == 27) 
 {
      document.write(banner [0], banner [6], banner [5], banner [4])
 }
 else
 {
      document.write(banner [6], banner [5], banner [4], banner[1])
 }
```

Is there a simple way to change this over with the

```
d.setUTCHours(-1) object?
```

Comment: Your code looks like JavaScript. You might want to look at [Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FgetTimezoneOffset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `document.write` by no way is Java but since the question is tagged as Java. You may try like this to display the time in EST

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

**EDIT:-**

However if you want to use that in Javascript then try to use [Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and
>   local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the
>   local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead.  For
>   example, if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard
>   Time), -600 will be returned. Daylight saving time prevents this value
>   from being a constant even for a given locale.

Answer (score 2):

Using [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('11/27/2013', 'America/New_York');
```